# setupNotification returns "Error already connected" whereas no connection request is send

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I'm making an Android application with some BLE interraction using the RxAndroidBLE API. I followd examples guidelines and samples from https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle

I establish a BLE connection with a specified device, later while connected I read and write characteristic with no problem, but when i try to setup notification for the battery level characteristic I get the following throwable error message : Already connected to device with MAC address XX:XX..."

I really don't understand the error in that context since I can read and write in characteristic with no problem.

I want to setup notification for this characteristic after an initial read of its value for specific purpose.

Here is a sample code that reproduce my problem :

```
private lateinit var device: RxBleDevice
private var connectionObservable: Observable<RxBleConnection>? = null
private var rxBleConnection: RxBleConnection? = null

private val connectionDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
private val connectionStateDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
private var notifyValueChangeSubscription = CompositeDisposable()


var enableBatteryNotificationRunnable: Runnable = Runnable {
  enableBatteryNotification()
}
private var myHandler = Handler()
val DELAY_BEFORE_ENABLE_NOTIFICATION: Long = 100


private fun connect() {
  connectionObservable = device.establishConnection(false)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

  connectionObservable?.let {
    connectionDisposable.add(it.subscribe(
      { rxBleConnection ->
        this.rxBleConnection = rxBleConnection
      },
      { _ ->
        Log.e("connect", "connexion error")                       
      })
    )
  }

  val state = device.observeConnectionStateChanges().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  connectionStateDisposable.add(
    state.subscribe(
      { connectionState ->
        Log.i("connect", "connexion state :$connectionState")
        if(connectionState == RxBleConnection.RxBleConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
            myHandler.postDelayed(enableBatteryNotificationRunnable, DELAY_BEFORE_ENABLE_NOTIFICATION);
        }
      }
    )
    { _ ->
      Log.e("connection listener", "connexion state error")
    }
  )
}

private fun enableBatteryNotification () {
  connectionObservable?.let {
    var observableToReturn =  it
      .flatMap { it.setupNotification(UUID_BATTERY_LEVEL) }
      .doOnNext {
        Log.i("NOTIFICATION", "doOnNext")
      }
      .flatMap { it }
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

    notifyValueChangeSubscription.add(observableToReturn.subscribe({ bytes ->
        var strBytes = String(bytes)
        Log.i("NOTIFICATION", "value change: $strBytes")
      }, 
      { throwable ->
        Log.e("NOTIFICATION", "Error in notification process: " + throwable.message)
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> setupNotification returns “Error already connected” whereas no connection request is send

Two connection requests are actually made — hence the error. From the `RxBleDevice.establishConnection()` Javadoc:

```
     * Establishes connection with a given BLE device. {@link RxBleConnection} is a handle, used to process BLE operations with a connected
     * device.
```

In your code there are *two* subscriptions to the `establishConnection()` `Observable`.

```
private lateinit var device: RxBleDevice
private var connectionObservable: Observable<RxBleConnection>? = null
private var rxBleConnection: RxBleConnection? = null

private val connectionDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
private val connectionStateDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
private var notifyValueChangeSubscription = CompositeDisposable()


var enableBatteryNotificationRunnable: Runnable = Runnable {
  enableBatteryNotification()
}
private var myHandler = Handler()
val DELAY_BEFORE_ENABLE_NOTIFICATION: Long = 100


private fun connect() {
  connectionObservable = device.establishConnection(false)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

  connectionObservable?.let {
    connectionDisposable.add(it.subscribe( // << Here is the first subscription
      { rxBleConnection ->
        this.rxBleConnection = rxBleConnection
      },
      { _ ->
        Log.e("connect", "connexion error")                       
      })
    )
  }

  val state = device.observeConnectionStateChanges().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  connectionStateDisposable.add(
    state.subscribe(
      { connectionState ->
        Log.i("connect", "connexion state :$connectionState")
        if(connectionState == RxBleConnection.RxBleConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
            myHandler.postDelayed(enableBatteryNotificationRunnable, DELAY_BEFORE_ENABLE_NOTIFICATION);
        }
      }
    )
    { _ ->
      Log.e("connection listener", "connexion state error")
    }
  )
}

private fun enableBatteryNotification () {
  connectionObservable?.let {
    var observableToReturn =  it
      .flatMap { it.setupNotification(UUID_BATTERY_LEVEL) }
      .doOnNext {
        Log.i("NOTIFICATION", "doOnNext")
      }
      .flatMap { it }
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

    notifyValueChangeSubscription.add(observableToReturn.subscribe({ bytes -> // << Here is the second subscription
        var strBytes = String(bytes)
        Log.i("NOTIFICATION", "value change: $strBytes")
      }, 
      { throwable ->
        Log.e("NOTIFICATION", "Error in notification process: " + throwable.message)
      })
    )
  }
}
```

This situation is a common source of confusion for people learning `RxJava`. There are [three paths](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/wiki/Tutorial:-Connection-Observable-sharing) to fix your situation. From least to most amount of work:

#### Share the `establishConnection` `Observable`

It is possible to share a single `RxBleConnection` with [`RxReplayingShare`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxReplayingShare). Change this:

```
  connectionObservable = device.establishConnection(false)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

To this:

```
  connectionObservable = device.establishConnection(false)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .compose(ReplayingShare.instance())
```

#### Use the `rxBleConnection: RxBleConnection?` property

Instead of:

```
  connectionObservable?.let {
    var observableToReturn =  it
      .flatMap { it.setupNotification(UUID_BATTERY_LEVEL) }
      .doOnNext {
        Log.i("NOTIFICATION", "doOnNext")
      }
      .flatMap { it }
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

    notifyValueChangeSubscription.add(observableToReturn.subscribe({ bytes -> // << Here is the second subscription
        var strBytes = String(bytes)
        Log.i("NOTIFICATION", "value change: $strBytes")
      }, 
      { throwable ->
        Log.e("NOTIFICATION", "Error in notification process: " + throwable.message)
      })
    )
  }
```

Make it:

```
  rxBleConnection?.let {
    var observableToReturn = rxBleConnection.setupNotification(UUID_BATTERY_LEVEL)
      .doOnNext {
        Log.i("NOTIFICATION", "doOnNext")
      }
      .flatMap { it }
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

    notifyValueChangeSubscription.add(observableToReturn.subscribe({ bytes -> // << Here is the second subscription
        var strBytes = String(bytes)
        Log.i("NOTIFICATION", "value change: $strBytes")
      }, 
      { throwable ->
        Log.e("NOTIFICATION", "Error in notification process: " + throwable.message)
      })
    )
  }
```

This is discouraged as you may end up with a `RxBleConnection` that is no longer valid as it may have been disconnected before calling `enableBatteryNotification()`

#### Change the flow of your code to use a single `.subscribe()`

This is a custom solution tailored to your exact use-case. Unfortunately with the information you have added is not enough to create a drop-in code replacement but it could look something like this:

```
device.establishConnection(false)
    .flatMap { connection ->
        Observable.merge(
            connection.readCharacteristic(uuid0).map { ReadResult(uuid0, it) }.toObservable(),
            connection.setupNotification(uuid1).flatMap { it }.map { NotifyResult(uuid1, it) }.delaySubscription(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        )
    }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        { /* handle ReadResult/NotifyResult */ },
        { /* handle potential errors */ }
    )
```

Where `ReadResult` and `NotifyResult` would be `data class` that take `UUID` and `ByteArray`

Comment: Thank you so much ! Your answer is very clear and exposes the benefits of every solution ! I went with the  RxReplayingShare and everything works fine now :)